# Detect if SplideJS is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, splidejs

How do I check if SplideJS is fully loaded, then I can do something?

I have tried the `load` event but it seems only work with page or iframe.
I have also tried the API

`if ( splide.state.is( Splide.STATES.IDLE ) ) { console.log('Done'); }`

OR

`if ( splide.state.is( Splide.STATES.MOVING ) ) { console.log('Done'); }`

I have also tried the `Events`:

```
splide.on( 'move', function () {
  console.log('Done');
});
```

or

```
splide.on( 'autoplay:play', function () {
  console.log('Done');
});
```

Can't believe all of the above not working.
Below is the minimal example code:

```js
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var splide = new Splide( '.splide' );
  splide.mount(window.splide.Extensions);
});
```

```css
.splide {
  height: 300px;
}

.splide__slide {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.0.7/dist/css/splide.min.css">

<section class="splide" aria-label="Splide Basic HTML Example">
  <div class="splide__track">
    <ul class="splide__list">
      <li class="splide__slide">Slide 01</li>
      <li class="splide__slide">Slide 02</li>
      <li class="splide__slide">Slide 03</li>
      <li class="splide__slide">Slide 04</li>
      <li class="splide__slide">Slide 05</li>
      <li class="splide__slide">Slide 06</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.0.7/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide-extension-auto-scroll@0.4.2/dist/js/splide-extension-auto-scroll.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Possible solution

> How do I check if SplideJS is fully loaded, then I can do something?

It depends on what you mean by «fully loaded».

Do you mean the «mounted» event? Let's consider this event.

Let's refer to the documentation: [Events - Splide](https://splidejs.com/guides/events/):

> #### `mounted`
>
> Fired right after all components are mounted. To listen to this event, you have to register the handler before calling `mount()`.

Therefore, it looks like the `mounted` event handler is the right place «to do something».

### Draft example HTML page

The page to test some event handlers, including the `mounted` event handler.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Splide example</title>
        <style>
            .splide {
                height: 300px;
            }

            .splide__slide {
                background-color: gray;
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.0.7/dist/css/splide.min.css">

        <section class="splide" aria-label="Splide Basic HTML Example">
            <div class="splide__track">
                <ul class="splide__list">
                    <li class="splide__slide">Slide 01</li>
                    <li class="splide__slide">Slide 02</li>
                    <li class="splide__slide">Slide 03</li>
                    <li class="splide__slide">Slide 04</li>
                    <li class="splide__slide">Slide 05</li>
                    <li class="splide__slide">Slide 06</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.0.7/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide-extension-auto-scroll@0.4.2/dist/js/splide-extension-auto-scroll.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                const splide = new Splide('.splide');

                splide.on('mounted', function () {
                    console.log('mounted: Fired right after all components are mounted.');
                });

                splide.on('active', function () {
                    console.log('active: Fired when the active slide is changed.');
                });

                splide.on('move', function () {
                    console.log('move: Fired right before the carousel moves.');
                });

                splide.mount(window.splide.Extensions);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```